# Top 10 cost where profit is < zero

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have following [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zckh0.png)

I want to show top 10 products where profit is less than equal to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these below steps-

**Step-1:** Add a visual level filter with profit <= 0. For example check the below image.

[image]

**Step-2:** Add another filter with show TOP 10 on the value column. Check the below image for example-

[image]

You will get your desired output.